# Exhaustive Model Selection using One or More Factor Variables in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, model-comparison

I am attempting to construct a Linear Model based on a large number of explanatory variables (including interaction terms between variables) two of which are factor variables. Using a factor variable in either regsubsets() or leaps() causes an error. Is there another function or package I can use that will incorporate factor variables when attempting exhaustive model selection?

Thank You

James

Comment: reproducible example?  maybe try the `glmulti` package?

Comment: yep,came here to suggest `glmulti` too but Ben beat me to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same issue when setting up the `leaps()` or `regsubsets()` using the x and y matrices.

However, `regsubsets(y~x1cont+factor(x2)..., data=data)` works for me. No error. Perhaps that may work for you?